# EJBQL/MySQL Regexes and IN

Tags: java, mysql, regex, ejbql

I have a list of Regexes and want to return those rows with a field which passes any regex. Is there anyway to something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo as f WHERE f.bar IN ("regex1","regex2");
```

It doesn't look like Regexes are possible at all in EJBQL so I'm guessing I have to use a native (MySQL) query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not combine the regexes into one?

```
"(?:" + regex1 + ")|(?:" + regex2 + ")"
```

So if `regex1 = "^.*foo(.*)bar"` and `regex2 = "baz(.*)frob$"`, you'd get

```
(?:^.*foo(.*)bar)|(?:baz(.*)frob$)
```

Comment: +1 Thats also a good idea. Less complicated and probably faster than my approach.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. At least not the way you think it is.

Do this instead: Insert the regexes as rows into a table. Then query

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  Foo AS f
  INNER JOIN Regexes AS re ON f.bar REGEXP re.pattern
```

Comment: +1 - funnily, I find this less complicated than my version :)

Comment: @Tim: Well… it requires an extra table and inserting rows into it before you can start with the query. Using a single, concatenated regex requires less housekeeping.